# is there a way to add a picture inside this "hovered" sign?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website and i managed to make a sign appear when i hover over a sentence. Inside that sign there is a text, but now i want to add a picture too. is that possible? how can i do it?

To clarify i want the picture inside the sign to dissapear when i take the mouse off the sentence. just like the sign itself and the text does.

this is an example of my codes:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mihojadeestilosTSlyrics.css"/>
<script src="jQueryAssets/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>   
    
<script>    
    
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $("#mensaje_frase0").hide();
        $("#frase0").hover(mensaje_on0, mensaje_off0);
        
    });

    
    function mensaje_on0(){
        $("#mensaje_frase0").show();
    }
    
    function mensaje_off0(){
        $("#mensaje_frase0").hide();
    }
    
</script>


</head>

<style> 
    
body
{
    background:url("../imagenes/speaknow/longlive.jpg"); /*La foto*/
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    background-position:120% 0%;
        
}   
    
    #mensaje_frase0{
        position: fixed;  /*queda en donde lo pusimos aunque cambiemos de posicion con la barra de desplazamiento*/
        left: 625px;
        top: 170px;   /*el espacio entre el cuadro y el tope VISIBLE de arriba*/
        width: 500px;  /*el ancho del cuadro. (el texto se acomoda adentro)*/
        height: 230px;
        background-color: #D7CFDA;
        font-size: 23px;
        padding: 25px;   /*El margen entre el texto y los bordes del cuadro*/
        padding-top: 40px;
        border: 2px #00F;
        font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "sans-serif";
        text-align: center;
    }   
    
</style>    
    
<body>
    
<div id="mensaje_frase0">THIS IS SOME TEXT INSIDE THE SIGN. I WANT TO ATTACH A PICTURE HERE TOO.</div>
    
    <h1><span id="frase0">Long Live</span></h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You probably don't need that `...hover(..)` code at all.  It can be done with some simple CSS.  See https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Answer (score 0):

Inside the div just add:

```html
<image src='<Image file here>'>
```

except be sure to change  to an actual image file location.